# Joomla page redirecting to error page with out showing any validation when invalid credentials are given

Tags: joomla

I have a problem with my joomla login page.
I am able to login into my site with valid credentials, but when I try to give invalid username and password there is not validation shown and it is redirecting to 404 error page, can any one please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Is this using the module or the login page or both?

Answer (score 0):

With joomla form validation you can validate form,
but if it will not work then you should apply jQuery validation on submit button click event.

and though it will not work then change your input **type submit** to **button** and redirect page using jQuery.